# Code Runner extension in VS Code does not give clean output, despite checking off "Show Execution Message" option

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I recently started using the **Code Runner** Extension for **Vs-Code** and despite checking off the `"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false` it keeps printing the file path, and some unwanted code after which it does print output but it's not clean, looks messy and hard to read the output. Here's what it does.

```
PS [path] \VsCode\ProblemSolving> cd "[path] \VsCode\ProblemSolving"
PS [path] \VsCode\ProblemSolving> cd "[path] \VsCode\ProblemSolving\" ; if ($?) 
{ g++ CodingCompetitionTools.cpp -o CodingCompetitionTools } ; if ($?) { .\CodingCompetitionTools }
```

This precedes the actual program output and I don't want to see this, just the clean program output.

Settiings.json for code-runner

```
"code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++",
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
```

[Refer this link for Vs-Code Marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your settings.json file?

I guess your setting looks like this?

```
{
  "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false
}
```

Maybe you have `code-runner.runInTerminal` set to true? If so, change it to **false**.

Just to debug this a little further, create a `.vscode` folder in the root of your current project (with a preceding dot) and inside of that folder a `settings.json` file with just:

```
{
  "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++",
  "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
  "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
  "code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
  "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": false
}
```

See if this changes anything.
Apologies if these steps are already obvious to you, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Added settings.json I had ```code-runner.runInTerminal``` as true, and changed it to false but did not work, it still gives that ugly message.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Your settings work just fine on my end.